# Is it possible to render express view as response to websocket event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

What I'm trying to do is to render an express view inside websocket event like this:

```
  socket.on('name', function () {
    //make client to render some express view
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is for HTTP. This doesn't really have anything to do with Express because you're just trying to render an HTML template inside of a websocket handler.

You need to use whichever template library's (Handlebars, Jade etc) render method inside the socket event handler. Here's a code sample using Handlebars:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

...

// Get the compiled template

var source = "<h1>Hi {{name}}!</h1>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

// Websocket gives us a name to render template with

socket.on('getNameHtml', function (name, callback) {

    callback(template({name: name}));
});
```